# Retornar mensagens através de exceções

Tags: php, laravel, exceção

Olá, me gerou uma dúvida com relação a forma mais "elegante" para o meu método exibir uma mensagem para o usuário.

Estou utilizando o seguinte `blade` com objetivo de retornar as mensagens, porém ele não retorna `Exceptions`, na verdade os exceptions travam minha aplicação sempre que são disparados.

Observem que no meu método `verificarUpdate` existem alguns cenários que talvez fossem interessante mostrar como *feedback* ao usuário.

Existe alguma forma de em alguns casos essas execeções serem covertidos para mensagem de erro? O laravel traz alguma facilidate para isso?

**feedback.blade.php**

```
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    {{ $error }}
                    <br/>
                @endforeach
        </div>
    @endif

    @if (isset($mensagem))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ $mensagem }}
    </div>
    @endif
```

**Classe RegistradorDeEncarregado**

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Encarregado;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Exception;

class RegistradorDeEncarregado
{

    public function desabilitarEncarregado(int $id): Encarregado
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $result = Encarregado::where('id', $id)
        ->update([
            'ativo' => 0]);
        DB::commit();

        return $this->verificarUpdate($result, $id);
    }

    private function verificarUpdate(bool $result, $id){
        $encarregado = Encarregado::find($id);

        // Cenário perfeito
        if($result && isset($encarregado)){
            return $encarregado;

        // Quando o id que vai sofrer a alteração já possui 
        // o mesmo valor do parâmetro
        }else if(!$result && isset($encarregado)){
            throw new Exception('Registro já se encontra com o(s) parâmetro(s) de alteração.');

        // Id não existente
        }else{
            throw new Exception('Não foi possível alterar o registro do encarregado.');
        }
    }
}
```

**Classe EncarregadoController**

```
    public function disability(
            Request $request,
            RegistradorDeEncarregado $registradorDeEncarregado)
    {
        $encarregado = $registradorDeEncarregado->desabilitarEncarregado($request->id);
        $request->session()
            ->flash(
                'mensagem',
                "Encarregado {$encarregado->nome} salvo com sucesso."
            );

        return redirect()->route('encarregado_listar_ativos');
    }
```

Comment: não consegui entender o exibir de forma mais elegante. Você está dizendo mensagens normais de seu sistema a partir de um array['success','danger','info','warning'] OU erros da aplicação, fatalError, etc? Edite sua pergunta para ficar mais claro e assim conseguirmos te ajudar melhor. Abraço

Comment: Pergunta editada. De forma geral, estou tentando trazer os exeptions citados no meu método para a tela do sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception não deveria ser mostrada, eles pode até conter dados sigilosos que não deveriam ser lidos por usuários comuns. Mas caso queira fazer eles aparecerem na aplicação é fazer:

```
try {
    ..codigo
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exceção capturada: ',  $e->getMessage();
}
```

Como você está usando blade, então no catch tem que retornar a view como a variavel da mensagem do exception.

Tipo:

```
try {
    ..codigo
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $mensagemErro = $e->getMessage();
    return view('paginaView', ['erro' => $mensagemErro]);
}
```

Comment: De certa forma, então, uma estratégia interessante seria retornar um mensagem genérica ao usuário e atravéz de algum tipo de log registrar a exceção gerada para posteriormente ser tratada.